# Replace content that is between to comments

Tags: javascript, regex, css-parsing

I would like to replace the content that is between two comments like

```
/**** Useless CSS ****/
.my-class{
 margin: 12px;
}

/* Several Lines after including other comments **/

/**** END Useless CSS ****/

.other {
 padding: 12px;
}
/* Hello */
```

So far I have:

```
[\/* Useless CSS \*\/](.|[\r\n])*?END Useless CSS \*\*\*\*\/?
```

But this doesn't work. I got an error in Regex101: Catastrophic backtracking

Comment: Please tag a language / tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your issue is the first part of your regex. You're using `[\/* Useless CSS \*\/]`, a character class, which means any character in this set. In other words any of the following characters (after removing duplicate letters): `/* UselCS`. That's definitely not your intention, but that's what it's doing. The code below removes the character class from the pattern so that it matches `/**** Useless CSS ****/` explicitly.

The second change is turning `(.|[\r\n])*?` into `[\s\S]*?`. There's no need to have regex check against two options each time. If it's a set of characters, just add them to the same character class. `[\s\S]` is a way of representing any character (including the newline character). Another way (works in JavaScript, but not many other regex engines) is to use `[^]`.

The third change was changing `\*\*\*\*` to `\*{4}`. Not only is this shorter and easier to understand, it also improves performance because the regex engine doesn't need to go token by token `\*`, then `\*`, then `\*`, etc. It's told to match `*` four times, so it does it in one go instead of 4. This means that `\*\*\*\*` takes four *steps* while `\*{4}` only takes one.

You may also append `\s*` to the end to remove additional whitespace.

```
\/\*{4} Useless CSS \*{4}\/[\s\S]*?\/\*{4} END Useless CSS \*{4}\/
```

```js
var s = `/**** Useless CSS ****/
.my-class{
 margin: 12px;
}

/* Several Lines after including other comments **/

/**** END Useless CSS ****/

.other {
 padding: 12px;
}
/* Hello */`
var r = /\/\*{4} Useless CSS \*{4}\/[\s\S]*?\/\*{4} END Useless CSS \*{4}\//gi

console.log(s.replace(r, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you *could* use regular expressions doesn't mean you *have* to use regular expressions.

```js
let css = `
.boat {
 float: left;
}

/**** Useless CSS ****/
.my-class{
 margin: 12px;
}

/* Several Lines after including other comments **/

/**** END Useless CSS ****/

.other {
 padding: 12px;
}
/* Hello */`;

const START_DELIMITER = '/**** Useless CSS ****/';
const END_DELIMITER = '/**** END Useless CSS ****/';

const left = css.slice(0, css.indexOf(START_DELIMITER));
const right = css.slice(css.indexOf(END_DELIMITER) + END_DELIMITER.length);

console.log(left + 'NEW STUFF' + right);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex almost works but you should consider some changes represented as below:

```
(\/\*+ Useless CSS \*+\/)(.|[\r\n])*?END Useless CSS \*\*\*\*\/
^  ^ ^               ^  ^
```

Explanations:

- Changing `[...]` to `(...)`. Former defines a character class, latter a group.
- Escaping `*` to express a literal character which otherwise works as a regex quantifier
- Quantifying `\*` with `+` to match `*` characters in a sequence.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUWERn/1)

also `(.|[\r\n])` which is supposed to match any character up to a point is a bad alternative for `[\s\S]` or `[^]` (in JS). Besides, I'd add `\s*` at the end of pattern to match left whitespaces:

```
\/\*+ Useless CSS \*+\/[^]*?END Useless CSS \*+\/\s*
                                                 ^^^
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUWERn/2)